# Limit of $n^{\frac{1}{n}}$.

Tags: real-analysis

We have to prove that $n^{\frac{1}{n}}$ converges to $1$. I have proved it using the binomial theorem where we can substitute $(1+t)$ in place of $n$ and proceed forward. However along with the question another approach was mentioned where we can make use of the Monotone Convergence Theorem. For this approach, I proved that $a_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ is increasing and using $a_n<a_{n+1}$ I proved that $n^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is decreasing after the third term. Also it is bounded as all terms are greater than $0$. So by MCT it should be convergent. But I am not able to evaluate the limit and am only able to prove its existence here. Please help.

Comment: Please take a few minutes to format your question: see https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I think you mean $(1+1/n)^n$, not $(n+1/n)^n$.

Comment: @A.E.Rosas . In 5 years I have never seen anyone except myself give a reason for a downvote. I rarely do, but I always explain it.

Comment: @martycohen yes you are correct. Sorry it was a typo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you have shown that $L=\lim_{n\to \infty}n^{1/n}$ exists, and is positive (because every $n^{1/n}\ge 1$),  then $$0<L=\lim_{n\to\infty}(2n)^{1/2n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}2^{1/2n}(n^{1/n})^{1/2}=L^{1/2}$$ because $2^{1/2n}\to 1.$

Answer (score 5):

Easiest proof:

By Bernoulli,

$(1+n^{-1/2})^n
\ge 1+n^{1/2}
\gt n^{1/2}
$.

Raising to $2/n$ power,

$n^{1/n}
\lt (1+n^{-1/2})^2
=1+2n^{-1/2}+n^{-1}
\lt 1+3n^{-1/2}
\to 1
$.

Answer (score 3):

$n^{1/n}=e^{\ln n^{1/n}}=e^{\ln n/n}$.  Now exp is continuous, and $\ln n/n\to0$.  So the limit is $e^0=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$a_n = n^{1/n} \implies \ln a_n = \frac{\ln n}{n} \implies \lim\ln a_n = 0 \implies \ln \lim a_n = 0 \implies \lim a_n = e^0 = 1$$